# How to arrange anagrams from shortest to longest?

Tags: python

I'm trying to arrange a list of anagrams from shortest to longest with the help of a text document. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried arranging the anagrams but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
# function that sorts letters in a string in ascending order 
def signature ( s ):
    t = sorted( s )
    return ''.join(t)

# function that builds a dictionary whose keys are the signatures of the
# words from words.txt and their values are the different anagrams for the 
# corresponding keys
#
def all_anagrams( filename ):
    # define a dictionary
    d = { }

    for w in open(filename):
        t = signature( w.strip().lower())
        if t not in d:
            d[t] = [ w.strip().lower() ]
        else:
            d[t].append( w.strip().lower() )


    return d 

#function to print contents of dictionary d
#that is, the list of anagrams previously stored in it 
def isAnagram(str1, str2):
    str1_list = list(str1)
    str1_list.sort()
    str2_list = list(str2)
    str2_list.sort()

    return (str1_list == str2_list)


#
# Let's test our solution
#                            
anagrams = all_anagrams("words.txt")
print_anagrams( anagrams)

#
['aah', 'aha']['aahed', 'ahead']['aal', 'ala']
This should be the output
#
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and sample output!

Comment: `sorted(anagrams, key=len)`

Comment: I've tried to run it but I've gotten errors. I can provide the words.txt file

Comment: 'aah', 'aha']['aahed', 'ahead']['aal', 'ala']['aals', 'alas']['aba', 'baa']['abacas', 'casaba']['abas', 'baas']['abasement', 'entamebas']['abasing', 'b

Comment: Add it to the question please! @Exodus1426